# Group by date hour in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, count

halo, i want to add `id` then `group by` product and date hour(without change the datetime to varchar). with data is:

```
datetime               product    sold
2020-10-27 08:51:00       A        50
2020-10-27 08:52:00       A        10
2020-10-27 08:52:00       B        20
2020-10-27 09:52:00       B        30
```

my query is:

```
select newId() as id, datehour(datetime) datehour, product, sum(sold)
from table_a
group by datehour(datetime), product
```

but did not work

my expected result:

note: the date hour should be datetime type not varchar

```
id   datehour               product    sold
1    2020-10-27 08:00:00       A        60
2    2020-10-27 08:00:00       B        20
3    2020-10-27 09:00:00       B        30
```

note: the date hour should be datetime type not varchar

any idea ?

Comment: Is `datehour` something you have written? Is the extent of "did not work"  the type of datehour or is there something else incorrect.

Comment: What is `newId()`?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Nick i'm using mysql workbench, newId is number of row (its must sequential)

Comment: Not workbench, it it MySQL 8.0 or 5.x?

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve with `newId()`. Other than that, you can get the result you want by using [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to strip the minutes and seconds from the times to get the `datehour` value; you can then `GROUP BY` that and `product` and [`SUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_sum) the `sold` values:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(`datetime`, '%Y-%m-%d %H'), '%Y-%m-%d %H') AS datehour,
       product,
       SUM(sold) AS sold
FROM table_a
GROUP BY datehour, product
```

Output:

```
datehour                sold    product
2020-10-27 08:00:00     60      A
2020-10-27 08:00:00     20      B
2020-10-27 09:00:00     30      B
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ettwyhqe6tDyfhoJnpXyJw/0)

In terms of generating the `id` value, if you are using MySQL 8+ you can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datehour, product) AS id,
       datehour,
       product,
       sold
FROM (
  SELECT STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(`datetime`, '%Y-%m-%d %H'), '%Y-%m-%d %H') AS datehour,
         product,
         SUM(sold) AS sold
  FROM table_a
  GROUP BY datehour, product
) a
ORDER BY id
```

For MySQL 5.x, you can simulate `ROW_NUMBER()` with a variable:

```
SELECT @rn := @rn + 1 AS id,
       datehour,
       product,
       sold
FROM (
  SELECT STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(`datetime`, '%Y-%m-%d %H'), '%Y-%m-%d %H') AS datehour,
         product,
         SUM(sold) AS sold
  FROM table_a
  GROUP BY datehour, product
  ORDER BY datehour, product
) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) i
```

In both cases the output is:

```
id  datehour                product     sold
1   2020-10-27 08:00:00     A           60
2   2020-10-27 08:00:00     B           20
3   2020-10-27 09:00:00     B           30
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ettwyhqe6tDyfhoJnpXyJw/1)

Comment: its work form me, is the datehour column datetime type ?  @Nick

Comment: @hinafaya yes it is

Comment: @hinafaya I've added two more queries (one for MySQL 8+, one for MySQL 5.x) which will generate the `id` value that you want.

Comment: thank u @Nick the query for mysql 8 works for me, superbbb